# What is the best way to write better/cleanish IF statements when you have multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring

I would like to refactor a few `if` statements I've encountered in some legacy code, to make them easier to read.

For example:

```
if (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4 || condition5 || condition6 || condition7)
```

I thought about maybe store the long condition list in a variable, give it a descriptive name and use that variable name in the `if` statement.

Comment: your solution is good if you're using those conditions in multiple places

Comment: otherwise it just adds more code

Comment: If you have a timecritic algorith where this condition asked very often you can order the conditions, if you know that one is very often true put it at the beginning than the rest need no to be proofed. If you use && than the put the often false condition to the beginnig.

Comment: A switch case statement may be more approprate in this case

Comment: thanks @frozen, lots of them are being used in just one place, so I guess that my idea won't work

Comment: @samhoooo Only if the condition are all about equality with the same value.

Comment: @NataliaDuran A descriptive name still is a good idea, even if you use the variable only once :-) If you're looking for more alternatives, please post your real code so that we can suggest something appropriate, which might be specific to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Having readable code is above all a question of presentation

you can do

```js
if ( (condition1)
  || (condition2)
  || (condition3)
  || (condition4)
  || (condition5)
  || (condition6)
  ) {
    // something to do...
  }
```

or:
*(dark and obscure method reserved for members of the sect of demonic coders)*

```js
switch (true) {
  case (condition1):
  case (condition2):
  case (condition3):
  case (condition4):
  case (condition5):
  case (condition6):
    // something to do...
    break;
 }
```

[edit]
You can also use an indent to show the hierarchy of conditions:

```
if ( (condition1)
  || (condition2)
  || ( (condition3-1)
    && (condition3-2)
    && (condition3-3)
    )
  || (condition4)
  || (condition5)
  || (condition6)
  ) {
    // something to do...
  }
```

Comment: No, please don't do that. OP asked for a cleaner way, not for a more obscure way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the good approach in this case is Consolidate Conditional Expression. You can combine all conditions in one function.

```
function isConditionsCorrect() {
    return (condition1)
        || (condition2)
        || (condition3)
        || (condition4)
        || (condition5)
        || (condition6);
} 

if (isConditionsCorrect()) return 0;
```